# Registry: Error pushing to registry: Authentication is required

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have installed a docker registry to push/pull my image, i login correctly to registry and my account is verified with a confirmation email. I have this error when push an image:

```
# sudo docker push myrepo/my-mysql
The push refers to a repository [myrepo/my-mysql] (len: 1)
b94fff6a5911: Image push failed 

Please login prior to push:
Username (user): user
Password: 
Email (my@email.it): my@email.it
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/user/.dockercfg.
Login Succeeded
The push refers to a repository [myrepo/my-mysql] (len: 1)
b94fff6a5911: Image push failed 
FATA[0031] Error pushing to registry: Authentication is required
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a current issue when pushing to the Docker Registry.
See [docker-registry/issues/995](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/995):

> commented 21 hours ago
>
> Having the exact same problem.

There was an [issue when pushing with Docker 1.6](https://status.docker.com/pages/incident/533c6539221ae15e3f000031/554293d934de855a3800061b), and it seems to persists with Docker 1.7